# tesseract 3.03 - input jpg file

Tags: linux, ocr, tesseract

I want to create a PDF with selectable/searchable text..

I have `source.png` which has gone through some pre-processing before OCR, and then I have `view.jpg` which is a compressed version of `source.png` to reduce the output PDF file

How do I define the `view.jpg` in the syntax?

```
tesseract -l eng source.png out pdf
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you can specify `view.jpg` in the command. The `out.pdf` already contains some sort of a compressed `source.png`.

Comment: no source.png is used directly without any post-processing or compression

Comment: From my testings, all the result output PDF files are smaller in filesize than the input image files.